# Change Outlook calendar default option when editing meeting requests

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, windows-registry, autohotkey, default-settings

I use Outlook from Office 365 to manage meetings with other people. Sometimes, after a meeting is set on our Outlook calendars, I want to edit notes associated with the meeting — but I don't want the other attendees to see my edits. If I change the notes associated with the meeting and then close the meeting dialog, I get this dialog box:

[image: Dialog box: What do you want to do with this meeting request?]

Note that the default option is "Don't save changes." I want to change the default to "Save changes but don't send." How may I do this? Is there a relevant registry setting? Or an AutoHotkey solution?

I've Googled around and looked at other posts on this forum, but I haven't found any relevant information. To be clear, I already know how to save notes that others won't see—this question is instead about how to change the default option in the dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the original poster, and I've discovered no good solutions to this problem. In particular, I've learned nothing about registry settings that may be relevant.

The only solution that I've found requires the use of AutoHotkey. One can create an AutoHotkey script, or add to an existing script, in a way that instantly changes the selected option when the dialog box appears. For details, see https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=107579.

As Christy notes above, one can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save "private" notes that are associated with an Outlook meeting. This isn't a solution to my problem, but it may be helpful information.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to edit notes associated with the meeting

Get the invite, save it, and close Outlook.

Open Outlook, open the invite and enter / edit your notes. That will not be seen by others .

If others have blocked Notes (that is, they are not your Notes) then other people may be able to see the changes.

I have added notes to an appointment so this should work for you.

> I want to change the default to "Save changes but don't send." How may
> I do this?

The screen shot you showed is just a current dialogue box and not a settings screen.

I looked in Outlook Options (Outlook, Options, Calendar) and there is not (so far as I can see) a setting that will change this default.

This is how Outlook works and (again so far as I know) the settings behavior is not adjustable in the Registry.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that works for me—I've done it myself on many occasions. But I want to know how to change the default option in the dialog box above. I'll edit the post to make this point clearer.

Comment: You can save Default for you (not the sender). I edited my post to clarify

Comment: Thank you, John. But I am afraid that I still don't see how to change the dialog box for which I've posted a screenshot. (I don't know what you mean when you say "Once you have edited Notes, you can change your Default Options." Are you referring to some sort of "Default Options" dialog box?)

Comment: Look in your Outlook Options as that should have your defaults. Some defaults will be in your appointment BEFORE you open a live appointment.

Comment: Your screen shot is not an Options box, just asking what you want to do at that point in the Appointment. Set up the Options you can in Outlook, Options, Calendar. Work through these and set them.

Answer (score 1):

Based on research and test, i didn't find the method to change the default option in Outlook client.

According to your description, i notice that you want to change the default to "Save changes but don't send". If you always need to save changes but don't send, as a workaround, you just need to **press Ctrl+S** instead of choosing "Save changes but don't send" option. In this way, the changes be saved and the updated meeting will not be sent.

Comment: Thank you, Christy. I do press Ctrl+S—when I remember to do so. But not infrequently, I absent-mindedly just attempt to close the appointment without saving changes, which brings up the dialog box that I showed above. And then I absent-mindedly hit Enter, which selects the default option: "Don't save changes." So I lose all of my changes. That's why I'm hoping to change the default option.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm afraid this default option can't be changed. At the moment I think the most appropriate workaround is to use shortcut key Ctrl+S to save. By the way, if you think my reply is helpful, please mark it as an answer,  which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If it is useful, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.